# Transfer row value into textbox from a form to the other (datagridview)

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I have a textbox and a button.

When the button is clicked it shows a DataGridView which outputs an ID and Name in a separate window (form). These are loaded with select statement from ms-access.

I would like that when I double click on any of the DataGridView rows, the ID is transferred to the textbox which is found in the other window (form).

(new to vb.net so please bear with me)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DataGridViews cellcontentdoubleclick event:

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellContentDoubleClick

    Form2.TextBox1.Text = sender.CurrentCell.Value.ToString

    End Sub
```

Note: Replace DataGridView1 with the name of your DataGridView and replace Form2 and TextBox1 with the name of your form and textbox.

'***

Just re-read your question, use current row on doubleclick and pass the index of the cell representing the ID:

```
Form2.TextBox1.Text = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString
```

Note: Replace '1' with the index of your column containing the ID.

Comment: This did not work. I think the textbox needs to be assigned to a variable which would hold the textbox text or something. Any idea mate?

Comment: This should work, works for me at least. There is no need for a variable to pass to the textbox as, either way, the value of the textbox will only be assigned once (either directly or through a variable). Couple of thoughts: 1) If your ID column is your first column then the above code should have Cells(0) instead of Cells(1), 2) Does your datagridview actually have the ID column, or have you chosen to remove it for viewing purposes? If this is the case, you should add it back to the datagridview, go to Edit Columns, and hide it instead, this way it can be referenced.